# Migrating users from Fedora, anything to look out for?

Tags: password, users, fedora

I've migrated around 300 users from a Fedora server to Ubuntu. I copied over all the relevant entries in `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow`, `/etc/group`, and `/etc/gshadow`. One thing that was a bit concerning is that Ubuntu starts the uid's at 1000 while Fedora at 500. I saw that I can adjust that starting number, but will that really cause any issues if I just leave it?

None of the users I copied over had conflicting uid's or gid's with what was already on the Ubuntu server.

I'm wondering if there is anything else I should look out for here. Maybe something that `useradd` does that I haven't taken into account?

Comment: No. Didn't end up having any issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't end up running into any issues during the migration. Just had to migrate the user entries in those files over. The password encryption was different, but ubuntu accounts for that when validating a password